# How to make a horizontal ListView with two row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

i am trying to show the catalog list in two row within horizontal GridView  or ListView
instead of  single row  the list data comes from server
The horizontal ListView  working fine with one row
How can I achieve this as the GIF bellow ?

bellow image  what  i have

bellow  gif   what i need

[image]
[[image: the ListView as needed1]

below full code The horizontal ListView  which is working fine with one row and i need to convert it to GridView so it can show two row and horizontal  scrollable

```
_catList() {
return Container(
  height: 150,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: catList.length < 10 ? catList.length : 10,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: 10),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            if (catList[index].subList == null ||
                catList[index].subList.length == 0) {
              await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ProductList(
                        name: catList[index].name,
                        id: catList[index].id,
                        tag: false,
                        updateHome: widget.updateHome),
                  ));
              if (mounted) setState(() {});
            } else {
              await Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SubCat(
                        title: catList[index].name,
                        subList: catList[index].subList,
                        updateHome: widget.updateHome),
                  ));
              if (mounted) setState(() {});
            }
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 5.0),
                child: new ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  child: new FadeInImage(
                    fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      catList[index].image,
                    ),
                    height: 100.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
                        erroWidget(100),

                    //  errorWidget: (context, url, e) => placeHolder(50),
                    placeholder: placeHolder(100),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  catList[index].name,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
                      color: colors.fontColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 15),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                width: 100,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use grid view to archive this thing. Here is a snippet of the configuration.

```
GridView.count(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                  children: ...)
```

Here  `crossAxisCount: 2,scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` is what you need.

Comment: this working if i use "  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical," but with " scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal," show blank page

Comment: finally it working the issue was the "height: 250," not include within GridView.count()

Comment: Good but this would be one of the better approaches since mention 250 height maybe vary depends on device dp.

Comment: you mean the fixed height is not recommended , if yes what is better

Comment: Get size from MediaQuery or use GridView

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `ListView.builder` with `itemCount: catList.length/2` and return a `Column` with two items (index and index+1)

or use `GridView.count`:

```
Container(
  height: 150,
  child: GridView.count(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: catList.isEmpty ? [Container()] : catList.map((cat) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: 10),
         child: GestureDetector(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 5.0),
                child: new ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  child: new FadeInImage(
                    fadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 50),
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      cat.image,
                    ),
                    height: 100.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) =>
                        erroWidget(100),
                    placeholder: placeHolder(100),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  cat.name,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
                      color: colors.fontColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 15),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                width: 100,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: it show error Colum's children must not contain any null values , but a null value was found at index 3

Comment: can u post the catList values? Also, are you using GridView or ListView (with a 2 rows column)?

Comment: i have edit the post with full current code

Comment: can I see how did you try to implement it with GridView instead of ListView?

Comment: itemCount: catList.length/2 and return a Column with two items (index and index+1) will give duplicated items (1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,error) so i tried GridView.count as your above code but its show error  " Colum's children must not contain any null values , but a null value was found at index 3 "

Comment: its happening because the catList.map((cat) {....}).toList() is returning an empty list. I'll update the code to try to solve the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236913/discussion-between-soma-and-pedro-pimont).

Comment: i have moved the catList out in Widget and called inside the children: of  GridView.count and working fine

Comment: sorry the delayed response, glad you did it

Answer (score 0):

i liked @pedro pimont approach.

Now i can render multiple row in horizontal list view with minimal code.
This is working example.

```
int itemCount = 12;
int divison = 2;
SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .35,
              child: ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(width: 20),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: itemCount ~/ divison,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      productItem((itemCount ~/ divison) * 0 + index),
                      productItem((itemCount ~/ divison) * 1 + index),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            )

Widget productItem(int index) => Card(
        color: Colors.grey[50],
        elevation: 1,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 80,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 0,
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                semanticContainer: true,
                color: secondaryLight,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(5)),
                ),
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text("${index + 1}"),
          ],
        ),
      );
```